# Best practices for displaying events and days

Tags: php, mysql

I have events (datetime)  in my MySQL database.
Days have 0, 1, or more events.

I want to show the upcoming 7 days, and below each day list the events happening that day (if any).

What would be the best practice to do so?

The easiest would be:

```
for(days) {
   for(mysql_query_get_events) {
      display_event
   }
}
```

but it would require to run the same big query for each day, and I believe this is very ineffective.  How would you proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along:

```
SELECT * FROM events
    WHERE event_date > NOW()
        AND event_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS)
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date ASC;
```

This would select all events in the upcoming 7 days

**Edit**: Just grab all events, loop through the days and keep popping results off the stack. E.g:

```
events = sql_query()
days = range(now, now + 7 days)

for (day in days) {
    echo day
    while events[0].date = day {
        echo array_shift(events)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not from a query standpoint, but more like a resource/layout one. I can easily get all the events at once, but I'm just trying to find the best way to display all days (regardless of events) and then display events below the appropriate days.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty subjective, but it would probably be more efficient to get all the upcoming events from the database, then iterate over the results.

```
mysql_query_get_upcoming_events
displaying_day = first_day
for(result_row){
    // !! Do not use '!=', use < or > depending on your intended display order
    while(displaying_day != result_row['day']){
        displaying_day++
        display_new_day()
    }
    display_event()
}
```

That's one larger query instead of multiple smaller queries.

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first. It works if there are multiple events happening the same day, however days that have no event will be skipped. That's why I was wondering if there was any kind of good practice regarding this matter.

Comment: That can be handled by filling in the days that are missing since you can calculate the last day and the new day. Updated example with that logic.

Answer (score 0):

The processing will need to be done either on the MySQL side or on the PHP side. If you wish to avoid placing the overhead multiple queries on the MySQL side, you will need to issue a query that gets all of the results for the next seven days:

```
SELECT `event_name`, `event_time` FROM `events` 
 WHERE `event_time` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND (CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Then reprocess the result set. Check the date of each result, and place it in an array that corresponds to a particular day.

```
while ( $event = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
     $event_array[date( 'l', $event['event_time'] )] = $event;
}
```

The alternative is to execute seven successive queries. You can benchmark your attempts to determine which is faster.